# Uploading image to apache server on clustered tomcat

Tags: image, apache, tomcat, upload

i have image upload logic in a clustered tomcat setup with Apache web server infront. Is there any way to upload image files on web server instead of tomcat, so that it will be accessed as like a static file when user tries to download the uploaded image file?

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>images</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>uk.co.foo.ImageServer</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>images</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```